# Order of "id" changed in subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have this query

```
SELECT bul.id 
FROM bul 
WHERE id  IN (SELECT hotid AS parentid 
FROM likehot 
WHERE hotid IN (SELECT id 
FROM bul 
WHERE  DATE  >= '1315976410') 
GROUP BY hotpid 
ORDER BY COUNT( hotid ) DESC )
```

when I runt this inner query

```
SELECT id 
FROM bul 
WHERE  DATE  >= '1315976410') 
GROUP BY hotpid 
ORDER BY COUNT( hotid ) DESC
```

I get

```
parentid
3655
3656
3622
3644
```

and when I run whole query I get

```
parentid
3656
3655
3622
3644
```

I really don't understand why the order of the ids change?

SOLUTION :-

```
<?php
 $query_hotpress_like = "SELECT hotid AS parentid FROM likehot WHERE hotid IN (SELECT id FROM bul WHERE  DATE  >= '" . (time() - (24 * 60 * 60)) . "') GROUP BY hotid ORDER BY COUNT( hotid ) DESC";
                $exe_hotpress_like = execute_query($query_hotpress_like, true, "select");
                $temp_like1 = array();
                foreach ($exe_hotpress_like as $kk => $exe_like) {

                    $temp_like1[] = "'" . $exe_like['parentid'] . "'";
                }
                $temp_like = str_replace(",''", "", implode(',', $temp_like1));

                $query_hotpress = "SELECT bul.id,photo_album_id,eventcmmnt_id,link_url,youtubeLink,link_image,id, mem_id, subj, body, bul.date,parentid, from_id, visible_to,image_link,post_via FROM bul WHERE id IN ($temp_like) ORDER BY FIELD(id,$temp_like ) LIMIT 5";

                ?>
```

execute_query() is the inbuilt function to get the result of query.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because for `IN` operator order doesn't matter.

If you need to sort outer query - sort outer query.

Comment: The ORDER BY in the subselect actually doesn't make sense at all and I wouldn't be surprised if the optimizer would simply drop it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specify an order for the "whole" query, the database is at liberty to return rows in any order it wants. The specific order you get is a result of how looking up rows is done when using the `IN` operator.

On your other query you are specifying an order yourself, so the database has to honor it.